# handle browser refresh event with angular 1.5 component routing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I have implemented `Angular 1.5 component routing`. I am looking for solution when a user refresh browser by click or by keyboard `F5`. It should redirect user to first page and should reset all entered/selected data.

Here is [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbONY8?p=preview). This have only two pages.

In my case, if user do refresh. User should be redirected to `First` page and all entered/selected data will be reset to default.

**Note: I am aware about Angular 1.5 component routing deprecation. Sad, that I got to know about this only after my app went to production. I have to provide some solution to user Until we migrate to Angular2.**

Here is code, which handles component routing:

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['ngComponentRouter']);

module.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

module.value('$routerRootComponent', 'myFirstApp');

module.component('myFirstApp', {
  templateUrl: "mainview.html",
  $routeConfig: [{
    path: '/',
    redirectTo: ['/First']
  }, {
    path: '/first',
    name: 'First',
    component: 'firstComponent'
  }, {
    path: '/second',
    name: 'Second',
    component: 'secondComponent'
  }]
})
```

Comment: ComponentRouter is deprecated;  It was designed to mirror the Angular2 Routing but changes in Angular2 made it impossible for this to stay in sync.  This implementation will not receive further updates, and you may want to reconsider designing around it.

Comment: yeah, but as of now mine app is in production. till we migrate to Angular 2. I have to provide some solution to user.

Comment: I was looking at your code, and see that `html5Mode` is enabled but it is still acting like it's not;  I'm not sure if this is a bug in the ComponentRouter or something else;  I'm trying to review this;  for now, you might need to add an `otherwise` clause to redirect to `/` on reload.

Comment: Is there any way I can inject native javascript code to handle this thing?

Comment: @Claies I have done it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it, only thing is one need to handle routing programmatically.
This line is doing the magic `window.onbeforeunload = $rootRouter.navigate(['First']);`

Make sure to inject `$rootRouter & $window` service.

```
module.component('firstComponent', {
templateUrl: "1.html",
controllerAs: "vm",
controller: function($rootScope, sharedService, $rootRouter, $window) {

  window.onbeforeunload = $rootRouter.navigate(['First']);

}
```